# how to access activemq jms custom header property; from camel route

Tags: routes, jms, apache-camel, custom-headers

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303891/how-to-set-jms-message-custom-header-using-xpath-in-camel-route) first. How can I access that custom header property value from "queue2"?outside of that route builder method or class.

I am using something like shown below. I dont find any methods in consumerTemplate API to get custom header properties.

```
ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
textMessage = consumerTemplate.receiveBody("activemq:queue2",10000,String.class);
```

that question is to set header using camel route. but this question about how to access that custom header outside of that class using queue name

Comment: You can use JMS API to browse a queue. Camel also has a browse endpoint.

Comment: I have updated the question with what i am trying to do for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set jms message custom header using xpath in camel route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303891/how-to-set-jms-message-custom-header-using-xpath-in-camel-route)

Comment: I asked that question. that is to set header using camel route. but this question about how to access that custome header outside of that class using queue name

Comment: In that question header has been set but I am not able to see in the activeMQ GUI queue message properties. but I am able to log that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to receive it as an `Exchange` to have all the data

```
ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive("activemq:queue2",10000);

String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String orderNumber = exchange.getIn().getHeader("orderNumber", String.class);
```

Comment: How can I read from activemq queue which message has that header value as orderNumber=123, So that I can consume only that message.

Comment: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549200/how-to-read-only-specific-queue-messages-based-on-message-header-property)