# how to read only specific queue messages based on message header property

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, message-queue, custom-headers

I have a list of messages in activemq queue. each message has a custom header property with value. How I should be able to access only those messages whose custom header property value = 123.?

I am using something like below to pick a message from queue. How to pick all messages which or a single message which has customHeaderProperty =123.?

```
ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
Exchange ex = consumerTemplate.receive("activemq:queueName",10000);
String data = ex.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String number = ex.getIn().getHeader("customProperty", String.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use message selectors on the consumer. A selector is a SQL like query. So you could write something like `myCustomHeader = 123`. Here is a [pretty good cheat sheet](http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml).

Since you tagged the question with apache-camel, I guess you are working with a Camel setup. In that case, you need to supply the selector to Camel. Something like `from("activemq:queue:myqueue?selector=myCustomHeader%3D123").`.

Comment: you mean by using consumerTemplate.?

Comment: Well, you tagged the question with Camel, so I thought you used it. Selectors can be used in plain java/jms as well as with spring based consumers as well.. or most/all jms-enabled frameworks.

Comment: Yes I am using camelContext. But I didn't get that. I have updated question with code,could you please elaborate. thanks.